# Making a Floating Egg Tray / Carton

Tags: wood, plastic

Objective: Make a floating platform to grow avocado seeds.

Conceptually this is a floating egg carton with 1 inch holes in the bottom of each egg cup. This allows the lower half of each avocado seed to be consistently covered in water since the platform will rise and fall with the level of the water.

What I have tried:

- Plastic 24-egg carton with styrofoam inserted.
- Drilling holes in a piece of wood

These are reasonable solutions. They tend not to adapt to the extra weight when adding lots of seeds.

What DIY idea do you have to solve this problem? Note that it needs to float to keep the lower half of the seed wet with rising and falling water levels.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You might want to tweak the question to clarify how this is a home improvement project so it doesn't get closed as off-topic.

Comment: Add some styrofoam to the wood - or replace the wood with a chunk of styrofoam with holes drilled in it. I sure hope you live somewhere that avocados actually grow, or this is a pointless exercise in house-plantery...